# What is this 40 cm long greenish and golden shining fish with brown fins?

Tags: rivers, fish, fish-identification

[image]
I caught this fish yesterday in St. John river in Canada. My father and I don't know what it is.

Fish like this have been caught recently (this Summer). Apparently, the fish was caught using worms.

Comment: Also you may want to consider adding some facts like length and weight.

Answer (score 5):

It appears to be a smallmouth bass based on this MN DNR [link](http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/fish/bass/small_large.html).

[image: s vs l mouth]

Comment: Yep, my thoughts, too. Smallmouth Bass.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @acpilot's answer, it appears New Brunswick, while not part of the native range of the smallmouth bass, is part of the expanded range of the fish. That further leads to a possible confirmation of the species. Here is the native and expanded range of the species in the United States [according to the US Geological Survey](https://nas.er.usgs.gov/queries/FactSheet.aspx?speciesID=396):

[image]

This map doesn't show the expanded range into Canada, but this paper from the Canadian Manuscript Report of Fisheries and Aquatic Sciences describes the species in Canada:

T.G. Brown, B. Runciman, S. Pollard, A.D.A. Grant, and M.J. Bradford: "[Biological Synopsis of Smallmouth Bass *(Micropterus dolomieu)*](http://waves-vagues.dfo-mpo.gc.ca/Library/337846.pdf)" [2009] *Canadian Manuscript Report of Fisheries and Aquatic Sciences*

Specifically, the authors include this map of the native and expanded ranges of the species in section 2 of their paper, "Distribution", which shows the species in New Brunswick:

[image]